# How to Delete Lines Not Containing ":" in notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

how to delete lines not contaning `:`

```
match1:follow
Star3:night
master
Hunt:Bock3
Roll
```

want to keep only lines with `:`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Open find replace dialog (CTRL+H)
2. Check "Regular expression"
3. Find what:
   `^[^:]*$`
4. Replace with:
    *(empty)*
5. press "replace all"

[image]

Comment: thanks so much Máté Juhász its get the job done i appreciate it

Comment: If you're interested in how that works, `[^:]` matches any character except a colon so the while thing matches lines where every character is not-a-colon.

Answer (score 5):

1. Control+F, go to "MARK" tab
2. Find what : :
3. check the box against "bookmark line"
4. click "Mark all"

All lines containing : will be highlighted.

5. Now, go to "Search" menu >> bookmark >> remove unmarked line.

Voila!

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8231096/8307806
Thanks to [Colin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1060304/colin)

Answer (score 0):

```
In Notepad++:

^(?!.*:).*$\n
→
empty
```

Comment: Why using a lookahead, it is useless here and slow down the process